# I want to insert a file to Oracle using BLOB column type over Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I want to save my file on Oracle Instance. I am using Hibernate for data objects. How can I insert files into Oracle Blob. Is there any sample code for this?

Comment: Do you really need to do that? It's much better to store the file somewhere on the file system saving the path in the database. Let the file system serve the file

Comment: Boris.. it's really one of the holywars themes how to manage OLE objects in database. What i really know is that Oracle russia manage their own files as Lob objects in database. You can search for some topics about that.

Comment: @Boris: there are valid reasons for storing blobs in the database, too. At the very least, you leverage the backup, transaction, access control, and network access features already provided by the database.

Comment: I should store file on Oracle. @Thilo I agree with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first you must annotate your entity field with @javax.persistance.Lob annotation.
Like this:

```
public class InfoMessage {

    private byte[] body;

    @Lob
    public byte[] getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(byte[] body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

and set it with bytes array. It's depends on wich File class you use. The first google result for java.io.File. I guess there's better solution for this operation.

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
// Get the size of the file
long length = file.length();

if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    // File is too large
}

// Create the byte array to hold the data
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

// Read in the bytes
int offset = 0;
int numRead = 0;
while (offset < bytes.length
       && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
    offset += numRead;
}

// Ensure all the bytes have been read in
if (offset < bytes.length) {
    throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
}

// Close the input stream and return bytes
is.close();
return bytes;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vanger. I am using xml configuration for hibernate not annotation.

Comment: @Vanger Can I store 3GB file on Oracle? Because with this code you are using Integer and length of byte array can be Max of Integer and this is less than 3GB file. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Lob` annotation is not Hibernate's one. It's `javax.persistence` and you can use it in entity bean with any hibernate mapping.
Yes, the big file is obvious problem for such example. But i can't find any workaround for this case. `FileInputStream` using int type value to represent offset point. 
I googled this one with similiar problem: http://www.coderanch.com/t/449055/Streams/java/JAVA-HEAP-SIZE-files-byte You can use solution with `SQLPrepareSteatement` if you use Java 1.6. Othwerwise you can try to use `BufferedReader` and somehow convert results to `byteArray[]` and try to beat another problem: you'll need so much memory as file size is.

**EDITED:** Another thing: Oracle can append data to it's clob\blob fields using dbms_lob.writeappend() procedure so you can avoid having all file in memory, but will GC perform clean as fast as `BufferedReader` read from file. And seems it's not a hibernate work to do this... jdbc and PreparedStatements back again.